# Javascript browser script to change a value

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to change the timer of a game with scripts I saw on sites and etc, I'm not really good at it but I just need some help and I hope it is not server sided,
anyway I looked into the source of the page and I found the timer code, it's going like that :

```
<div class="orange_control timer">
    <span class="min">04</span>:<span class="sec">00</span>
</div>
```

Now I want to ask if there's any Javascript script I can write into the browser to change the min and sec values,
for example:
"javascript: sec=10;" (of course it didn't work)
thanks for anyone that is helping!

Answer (score 0):

this is pure JS code this will change

```
   <script language="javascript">



function changetime() {
        var dt = new Date();
       document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML=dt.getSeconds();
}
setInterval('changetime()', 1000);  
</script>

<div class="orange_control timer">
    <span id="min" class="min">04</span>:<span id="sec" class="sec">00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I didn't really understand how to use it, I will explain better:
There is already page and if I get into the page details I get the class orange control timer, now I want to change those values with a script that I will paste in the browser URL, for example I want to change the min value to 05 and the sec value to 35, how do I do that?